# integer number division to decimal number in bash script

Tags: floating-point

in bash script i have to change the value of $R , so i have to division to decimal number but it's impossible

```
R=$((R/(15.6))) #for convert move in millimeter to second
```

i try to

```
R=$((R/(156/10))) #for convert move in millimeter to second
```

but it doesn't work too

Comment: Try `R=$(bc -l <<< "$R/15.6")`

Answer (score 1):

bash only handles integer numbers, but you could simply use `bc` to do the calculations.

Comment: *Start point*
*/bin/timelapse: line 36: bc: command not found*